# Scraping Javascript loaded pages using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to webscrape, using Python, the comments from a BBC article: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/education-37750489/comments?comments_page=1&initial_page_size=10&filter=none&sortBy=Created&sortOrder=Descending#

The comments module is in Javascript, with buttons for the next pages. However, I can't find an AJAX url - there is one link from having a look on the Network console, but that doesn't work: https://ssl.live.bbc.co.uk/modules/comments/?siteId=newscommentsmodule&parentUri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.co.uk%2Fnews%2Feducation-37750489%2Fcomments&forumId=__CPS__37750489

However, I want to scrape multiple pages, but when I try and change the 'page=x' in the first page, it only takes me to the first page.

I've thought of using Selenium/Dryscape, but I'm not sure how I can get to each of the pages to run them.

Comment: "I've thought of using Selenium/Dryscape, but I'm not sure how I can get to each of the pages to run them." can you explain this more? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I need to find a way to get to a URL for each of the comments pages in order to run a scrape. I was thinking of running a screen scraper like Selenium or Dryscrape, but I still need to get a URL to get to access each page in the first place, right?

Comment: share what code you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

you can try the `copy as Curl` command by right clicking on the xhr request in the network section.

this is what i get

```
curl "https://ssl.bbc.co.uk/modules/comments/ajax/comments/?siteId=newscommentsmodule^&forumId=__CPS__37750489^&filter=none^&sortOrder=Descending^&sortBy=Created^&mock=0^&mockUser=^&parentUri=http^%^3A^%^2F^%^2Fwww.bbc.com^%^2Fnews^%^2Feducation-37750489^%^2Fcomments^%^3Fcomments_page^%^3D1^%^26initial_page_size^%^3D10^%^26filter^%^3Dnone^%^26sortBy^%^3DCreated^%^26sortOrder^%^3DDescending^&loc=en-GB^&preset=responsive^&initial_page_size=10^&transTags=0^&comments_page=4" -H "Origin: http://www.bbc.com" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.44 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01" -H "Referer: http://www.bbc.com/news/education-37750489/comments?comments_page=1^&initial_page_size=10^&filter=none^&sortBy=Created^&sortOrder=Descending" -H "Cookie: BBC-UID=f5b82387c6a5f59cfb1e4e702165956d3c4a59fc40f0a0cc2289331f59e23c7f0Mozilla^%^2f5^%^2e0^%^20^%^28Windows^%^20NT^%^2010^%^2e0^%^3b^%^20Win64^%^3b^%^20x64^%^29^%^20AppleWebKit^%^2f537^%^2e36^%^20^%^28KHTML^%^2c^%^20like^%^20Gecko^%^29^%^20Chrome^%^2f55^%^2e0^%^2e2883^%^2e44^%^20Safari^%^2f537^%^2e36; BGUID=e50803c74685961b76a3bae761e263da9bbf269019d8d4abbed18707f72c1098; s1=208.5.385837657400859000FDD0E52985" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --compressed
```

Or you can use selenium to click on the pagination buttons directly

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.comments-pagination-page.comments-pagination-page-{} a'.format(pageNumber)).click()
```

here the `li.comments-pagination-page.comments-pagination-page-3` is the li tag for the 3rd pagination button in the page.

Comment: if you `click()` the `<a>` tag using the driver the page in the session will change and hence you wont need a URL.